# await not working with async in Flutter [Await applied to User which is not a Future]

Tags: firebase, flutter, async-await, firebase-authentication, future

when i am using await with async ,it's asking me to remove await.what is the reason ??
please check image, it's mandatory to use async and await with Future then why it's asking to remove. i am new on this language please help..Thank you.

**I am using firebase version -   firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1**

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/arM35.png
```

Answer (score 0):

await is applied to an expression or a variable when it return future of an object but here
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser is returning  User not Future so you need not to use await here still you can use it as it is simply a warning not an error or exception
thanks i hope it help

Comment: From your explanation, my doubt has been clarify ,Thanks for help.